# Where Flutter creates database on device? (testing with my phone)

Tags: android, database, flutter, flutter-test

My app creates a database using the path provided by "getApplicationDocumentsDirectory" (on Android). When user log in, it saves the user's primary key, email, and Auth Token of the user in the database obtained from API. When the user logs out app will delete all data associated with that primary key.

During testing, I only implemented the login option and logged in. The user gets saved in the database. Now SQLite raises a unique constraint error on the primary key and this user can't log in again. Now I have logout functionality up and running, and I don't know how to log out this user.

I think deleting the database from phone memory might help but can't find it on my phone.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app from your phone? I am not totally sure, but I think it should also delete all data of the app.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, uninstalling works. However, clear data, cache didn't work for me.